# Evaluating double sums with related indices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am having trouble finding any techniques that allow people to solve double sums where the indices rely on each other. For example, suppose I have the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n i + j$$

What techniques can I use to eliminate the sums, and arrive at a simple algebraic expression in terms of only n?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find the sum or to a way to simplify the indices?

Comment: Ind the end, I want to be able to find the sum. If simplifying the indices helps achieve that goal, then great. I have never learned how to simplify indices in sums. Does that reduce this to only one index variable?

Comment: I've just indicated a way to find the sum. There also tecniques to simplify the indices (e.g. double counting) but I can see a clever way now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(i+j)}&=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(i+j)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(i+j)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=2}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i+(j-1)j\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}(j-1)j+(j-1)j\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)j\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n(n+1)}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the index region somewhat more conveniently.

  Note that we assume the index $j$ is a *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* variable and so we write $(i+j)$ consequently in parenthesis.
- In (2) we exchange the sums so that the inner sum starts now with $i=1$.
- In (3) we use the summation formula $\sum_{k=1}^n c= n\cdot c$.
- In (4) we use the summation formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.
- In (5) we do some simplifications and start with $j=1$ without changing anything since we are adding $0$ only.
- In (6) we use the formula $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$ and the same as in (4).
- In (7) we do some final simplifications.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had never hear of bound variables before, and had no idea that simply changing the order of the summation would be so useful! His was very helpful!

Comment: @MegaZeroX That's indeed a better way!

Comment: @MegaZeroX: You're welcome. If you want to dig deeper into this subject I recommend chapter 2: "Sums" of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by D.E. Knuth, R.L. Graham and O. Patashnik.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer OK, thanks for the recommendation! I've heard of it, but never had time to give it a shot. I'll hopefully have time for that when summer comes.

Answer (score 2):

We can sum at first the inner summation that is

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n i + j=i\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1 +\sum_{j=i+1}^n  j=i(n-i)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$

and then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n i + j=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(i(n-i)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-\frac32i^2+i\left(n-\frac12\right)\right)$$

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't realize that we could simply evaluate the inner sum, substituting i in, and then use that new expression to solve the outer sum. Thanks!

Comment: @MegaZeroX Yes that's the standard way to proceed. I don't know if in that case we can also proceed with some clever manipualtion.